# en js como obtener una ip local sabiendo el puerto en el que se esta usando

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ip, puertos

Tengo un server.js lanzado con node que lo que hace es abrir un webservice para enviar y recibir texto.
Lo tengo puesto en localhost:8080 (por ponerlo en uno) el tema es que lanzando una web que le envía texto y en otro navegador lo recibe, todo correcto, pero eso está todo en mi pc.

Lo que necesito es que la web, si la cargo desde el móvil (TODO EN RED LOCAL) quiero que, **sabiendo el puerto, me saque que ip la está usando** para así conectarse a esa y poder enviarle texto, es decir desde un navegador externo al pc pero en la misma red local.

he probado con

```
const portNumber = 8080; // Cambia esto al número de puerto que desees
const ipAddress = window.location.hostname;
var divip = document.getElementById("ipes");
divip.innerHTML = ipAddress;
console.log(`La dirección IP local asociada al puerto ${portNumber} es: ${ipAddress}`);
```

pero no me saca que ip es...

Comment: Utiliza lo que son `sockets` o `web sockets` para tu proposito, todo lo hace mas facil, ya que si lo pensamos bien, para que mas necesitarias la direccion IP?, bueno, en caso de que igual la necesites, `nodejs` dentro de si te puede decir la direccion IP que esta usando la instancia.

Comment: utilizo en server.js un websocket, y necesito la dirección ip por que al ejecutar el servidor en local, si accedo desde otro ordenador en la misma red, necesito saber la ip del servidor para que se conecte

Comment: Dejame entender algo, lo que quieres es que un cliente principal, digamosle a este un super usuario sea capaz de ver que otros estan conectados en la red junto con su puerto y direccion IP a la direccion en la que tienes tu servidor?, por ejemplo, digamos soy un usuario normal, y me conecto al servidor web socket, entonces que el super usuario se de cuenta de esto e informe de ello, ya sea de alguna forma para guardar esa direccion IP o usarla de alguna manera por el "principal", es este el funcionamiento que deseas?

Comment: no, mas bien, que una vez el servidor (por ejemplo ip 123.123.1.2:8080) se esté ejecutando y funcione bien, que otro usuario (siempre en red local nada de internet) sabiendo que el puerto es 8080, pueda sacar cual es la ip que se está usando para poderse conectar al servidor, es decir, conectarse al servidor de otro pc en local sin saber la ip

Answer (score 0):

La manera manual de hacerlo es ejecutando el comando "[ipconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig)" en la terminal e ir viendo todos los adaptadores de red, en el apartado IPv4 Address te muestra la información que deseas (IPv4 Address...... **: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx** ).

Para lograrlo podrias

1. [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)
2. Procesar la salida de la terminal. Dividir ("[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)") el string para que te de cada adaptador con su información.
3. Dividir nuevamente esos strings para que te den la información que esperas
4. Regresar esa información como un arreglo y permitir al usuario ver todos los adaptadores de red.
5. El usuario selecciona su adaptador de red y se muestra la Dirección IPv4

**Debes de tener en cuenta que no todas las personas tienen el sistema operativo en Español o Ingles**